# Iframe inside a modal window doesn't change source

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to make it so when you click on the video thumbnail, the video pops up in an iframe inside a bootstrap modal window. Right now I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but the script sometimes opens the modal window with the source, sometimes it does without the source. It never seems to open the last four videos though.

It seems sort of random and makes no sense to me. Also, it doesn't seem to like to switch between the categories.

Here is some of my JS code that I suspect might be breaking stuff. More details can be found in the link attached and in the fiddle.

```
function showVideos(channel) {
if (!isFirstPass) {
    $('#addedContent').remove();
}
$('#dropdownVideoPicker').append('<div id="addedContent"></div>');

var arr = $.map(channel, function (data) {
    getTitle(data);
});

$.when.apply($, arr).then(function () {
    $('#addedContent').hide();
    $('#addedContent').slideDown();
    isFirstPass = false;
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: ($('.category-shape:nth-of-type(6)').offset().top)
    }, 1000);
    console.debug('got only here');
    grabYtId();
});
}


function grabYtId() {
console.debug('got here 1.0');
$('.videoThumbnail').on('click', function () {
    console.log('got here 1.1');
    var $ytId = $(this).attr('src').slice(27, -6);
    console.log($ytId);
    showModalWindow($ytId);
});
}


function showModalWindow(Id) {
var $theModal = $("#videoModal"),
    iframe = $("#iframe"),
    videoSRC = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + Id,
    videoSRCauto = videoSRC + "?autoplay=1&rel=0&controls=1&showinfo=0";
iframe.attr('src', videoSRCauto);
$('button.close').click(function () {
    iframe.attr('src', ' ');
});
$theModal.on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
    iframe.attr('src', ' ');
});
}
```

Link to live website, if you want to see how exactly it looks

https://vast-atoll-28054.herokuapp.com/video.php

Fiddle link (I wasn't able to make the Ajax call work here):

https://jsfiddle.net/ebkgry99/2/

I think it might have something to do with this part

```
function grabYtId() {
console.debug('got here 1.0');
$('.videoThumbnail').on('click', function () {
    console.log('got here 1.1');
    var $ytId = $(this).attr('src').slice(27, -6);
    console.log($ytId);
    showModalWindow($ytId);
});
}
```

but I don't know for sure.

I think that this event is being attached at the wrong time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed that listener `$('.videoThumbnail').on('click'...` is never applied to content since there's no `.videoThumbnail` nodes yet.

You should put the invoking of `grabYtId()` within your async callback like this:

```
$.when.apply($, arr).then(function() {
    $('#addedContent').hide();
    $('#addedContent').slideDown();
    isFirstPass = false;
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: ($('.category-shape:nth-of-type(6)').offset().top)
    }, 1000);
    console.debug('got only here');

    // Put it here when there should be .videoThumbnail in the DOM tree already
    grabYtId();
});
```

If by any chance that's not the right place you can execute the following piece of code when invoking `grabYtId()`:

**SOLUTION 2**

```
var t, counter = 0;
t = setInterval(function(){
  counter++;
  if(counter === 100) {
    // Stop interval if it fails 100 times to find nodes
    clearInterval(t);
  }

  var videoNodes = $('.videoThumbnail');
  if(!videoNodes.length) return;

  clearInterval(t);
  grabYtId();
}, 300);
```

It waits until `.videoThumbnail`  are added to DOM and then attaches the listener.

**SOLUTION 3:**

You may try but applying it just once:

```
$('#addedContent').on('click', '.videoThumbnail', function(){
  var $ytId = $(this).attr('src').slice(27, -6);
  showModalWindow($ytId);
});
```

Comment: i may be wrong, but I believe this is the way I have it right now

Comment: In https://vast-atoll-28054.herokuapp.com/video.php no you're not and I modified it and it loads the videos just fine

Comment: Are you sure that for the ones at the bottom in the community part work? I just did the same thing and it didn't help. or I'm just dumb.

Comment: I am sure that the listener callback isn't invoked in the problematic dialogs and the reason is because there's no `.videoThumbnail` in the DOM tree you may try the next solution I've posted

Comment: Ok, the set interval saved me. Dude, you're brilliant! Thanks for the explanation! Solution 2 works like a charm. So the set interval counts the thumbnails. But here? `if(!videoNodes.length) return;`  And why stop the interval?

Comment: An interval is the wrong way to go about this. You (both?) want to go read up on _event delegation_, that is the proper way to handle events on elements that are only added to the DOM later ...

Comment: So create a custom event after everything gets loaded and dispatch it? I tried but didn't work

Comment: Just be careful because there might be a case when you add the listener multiple times if a guy clicks buttons `See The Videos` quickly one after another 10 times let's say. Check weather that doesn't cause bugs. 
Indeed delegating listener is a better solution #CBroe is right

Answer (score 1):

An interval is not a good solution to this.

The proper solution to handle events on elements added to the DOM only later is *event delegation*.

You want something like this,

```
$('#addedContent').on('click', '.videoThumbnail', function () {
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this binds a click handler to the already existing
// #addedContent container element,
//                     and this ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ makes it execute your
//                callback function only when the event happend on such an element     
    console.log('got here 1.1');
    var $ytId = $(this).attr('src').slice(27, -6);
    console.log($ytId);
    showModalWindow($ytId);
});
```

and you want to remove the `grabYtId` function, an instead place this code somewhere where it will get executed *once*.

Since the AJAX stuff in your fiddle doesn't work, it is hard to create a live example to demonstrate this; but if you just copy&paste the above code snippet into the browser console and press enter, right after the page has fully loaded, before you even press one of the "load videos" buttons, you should already see it basically working.

Comment: So this waits for the .videoThumbnail to be attached to the #addedContent? And it attaches to every new element in there that get's added?

Comment: No, as I tried to explain via the comments in the code snippet, this attaches one single event handler to the already existing `#addedContent` element. Since events _bubble up_ through the DOM, this will then “catch” all the click events that happen on descendant elements of `#addedContent` as well - _all_ of them, no matter which element.

Comment: By specifying `'.videoThumbnail'` in the second `.on` parameter you then tell jQuery that of all those possible click events, you want your function to only handle those that actually occurred on elements with the class `videoThumbnail`. _This_ check happens at the time the click occurs - so it does not matter any more when this element was added to the DOM.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand. So it attaches the listeners to the class each time `#addedContent` is clicked? I just don't understand with all the async going on how and why it works.